# Assigning to an element of a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user defined control called Date with a year element. The code is as follows:

```
   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" class="form-control" AppendDataBoundItems="true"    runat="server"  DefaultValue="0">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
   </div>
```

The accessor is:

```
public string Year
{
    get
    {
      return ddlYear.SelectedValue;
    }
    set
    {
      ddlYear.SelectedValue = value;
    }
}
```

However when I try to assign to it this way, it does not retain the value. It stays as "0" which is the default value.  Is there another way to assign this?

```
Date.Year = year;
```

Comment: This might be off topic, but there is no such thing as a constructor for a property. What you designated as a "constructor" is actually called the property accessors.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the SelectedIndexChanged event handler for the dropdownlist. Inside that event handler write the code
 `Date.Year = year; // Or any other value.`